# If $x,y \in R$ and $x<y\implies x^2>y^2$ then:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $x,y \in R$ and $x<y\implies x^2>y^2$ then:

a). $x>0$

b). $x<0$

c). $y>0$

d). $y<0$

My Attempt:

Here, $x<y \implies x^2>y^2$ but How?
As for example: Let $x=0.001$ and $y=0.1$.
So, 
$$0.001<0.1$$
Squaring Both Sides, We get:
$$0.000001<0.01$$
??

Comment: Looking at the options might suggest that signs play a big role.

Comment: $$-3<+2 \to +9>+4\\-5<-2 \to 25>+4 \\x<0,|x|>|y|$$

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the implication is false when x is positive. So x must be negative and the answer is (b).

Comment: The answer is NOT b. -5 <6 but 25<36.

Comment: This does not imply that y must be negative, however, only that |y|<|x|. All we can say for certain is that x must be negative

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima, "$-5<6$, but $25<36$" does not suit the condition, so it cannot be considered in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof why $b) x<0:$

$$x<y \Rightarrow x<x+t, t>0 \Rightarrow x^2>x^2+2xt+t^2 \Rightarrow x<-\frac{t}{2}<0.$$

Answer (score -1):

Only possibility of holding inequality is that y must be negative. I.e option (d) is correct.
We check this by an example
-2<-1 imply 4>1 (square of both sides)